# Can't install latest version of my package from test.pypi.org

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I am trying to learn python packaging following the [official tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and stuck at one of the steps. I managed to build the package and upload it on test.pypi.org which you can find [here](https://test.pypi.org/project/sem-nCG/). However, when I try to install it in a different test environment (following the tutorial), it does not install the latest version. It always downloads version `0.0.1` which is totally surprising to me. I used the following two commands to install it (but both of them failed) --

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ sem-nCG  # from test.pypi package page
```

```
python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --no-deps sem-nCG  # from the tutorial
```

I had made some mistake in version `0.0.1` and am at the version `0.0.3` right now but I am not able to test it out.

Could anyone please help me out? I did not find much help regarding this issue.

P.S. - As you would notice, the older versions (`0.0.1` and `0.0.2`) are missing on test.pypi. I deleted them thinking it will solve the issue but it did not.

Thanks,
Naman

Comment: Already tried to reinstall the whole package? 
Also you can add `--upgrade` to your command, this will upgrade the package to latest version.